# Orbeon 4.3 throws ValidationException when trying to access MySQL

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, orbeon

After solving my initial properties-local.xml issue, I have moved on to another problem. I initially had a naming context error that I resolved by changing the value of `oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*` to be `db` matching my resource definition for JBoss.

Now, when saving a form definition I receive an error dialogue with the message.

```
There was an error communicating with the database. 
Please contact the application administrator.
```

When I check the server.log I noticed that the first exception occurred after clicking continue after inputting the new form name, title and description.

The exception is this:

```
21:41:26,312 ERROR [org.orbeon.oxf.controller.PageFlowControllerProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-8) error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/service/persistence/crud/orbeon/library/form/form.xhtml"}
21:41:26,406 ERROR [org.orbeon.oxf.controller.PageFlowControllerProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-8) 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: line 18, column 47 of oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/proxy.xpl (executing process|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml                                                        |reading page model data output|  18|
|······················································································································|
|element=<service path="/fr/service/persistence/.*" model="persistence/proxy.xpl"/>                                    |
|model  =persistence/proxy.xpl                                                                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/proxy.xpl                                                |executing processor           |  18|
|······················································································································|
|element=<p:processor name="fr:persistence-proxy"/>                                                                    |
|name   ={http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner}persistence-proxy                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                             |
```

I'm assuming my properties-local.xml needs some work. Here are the contents:

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
  <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="db"/>
  <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource" value="db"/>
</properties>
```

I had the same error without the second property.

Comment: Your provider cannot be `db` unless you have a provider called `db`. But it looks like you want to use the MySQL provider, so you do need <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>. So you have to revert your first change.

Comment: Does the JBoss resource definition need to be named `mysql` as well? The documentation uses `db`

Comment: I now have form definitions and data saving in MySQL. Now to figure out why the form search is failing.

Comment: The *datasource* name must match that specified in `oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource`.